# Why is react giving me an error that it expected a function call and instead got an expression?

Tags: reactjs

Ive seen a lot of this question here but none of the answers provided seems to be answering my scenario.

I have this code that looks so simple

```
   const getSpecificMedicineWithId = (number) => {
    const filteredData = mockListOfMedicines.find((medicine) => {
      medicine.medicineId === number;
    });

    return filteredData;
  };
```

I get this error

```
 Line 60:7:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

What could go wrong with such a simple function? **Please help.**

Comment: whats there at line no 60?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to return value from the find call back,hope this will help.

```
const getSpecificMedicineWithId = (number) => {
const filteredData = mockListOfMedicines.find((medicine) => {
  return medicine.medicineId === number;
});

return filteredData;
};
```